# Access HTML page on local network

Tags: html, tomcat

Say I have this HTML page , I want when some one on my local network type my(ip) or my computer Name in a browser to view that HTML page

Comment: You have to run a webserver on your computer, and put that HTML page in the `index.html` file in its root folder.

Comment: okey now I want the same thing when I enter my computer name , also , is there a way to remove the :8080 from the address ?

Comment: To enter the computer name you have to run a DNS server on the network, to translate names to IPs. Or give every machine a hosts file. To remove `:8080` you have to run the webserver on port 80.

Comment: Configure your webserver to host on port 80, not 8080. 

8080 is often used as a server default since it's a common choice for experiments that you aren't yet ready to make publicly available, but 80 is the official default port for HTTP.

And, yes, you need to register with a domain name server, and make sure the client checks that DNS. Run one locally, or your ISP may offer a Dynamic DNS that you can use -- but that will make your machine name visible on the public Internet.

Comment: If I control the router , instead of using a DNS , can I do something like rerouteing to my localhost ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just have to edit the httpd configuration file and ensure that the default port is set to 80, as by default it should use that anyhow, 8080 is the alternate one.

If you use a local network then the rest of the users in it should be able to reach the website on `http://your-computer-name`, otherwise if for any other reasons that's not configured then they'll have to use the IP address.

They can also edit their local hosts file (in Windows for eg.) and have something like:
your.IP     any-name

any-name being either your computer name or website name, as it will be a direct maping

Comment: where is that , httpd file ? am using tomcat 7.0